How do I obtain the Signature Hash Algorithm from the certificate Signature Algorithm on Windows?
Given a certificate parsed with CNG on Windows, I am recommended to extract the "Signature Algorithm" as follows:
    hashAlgorithm.pszObjId = cert->pCertInfo->SignatureAlgorithm.pszObjId;

On a particular certificate I get szOID_RSA_SHA256RSA.
Windows docs and examples tell me to pass szOID_RSA_SHA256RSA to CryptSignMessage, and this results in a successful PKCS7 signed response, however bouncycastle refuses to parse the signed response, claiming that 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 (SHA256withRSAEncryption) is not valid.
This is technically true, bouncycastle wants 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 that corresponds to SHA256. This is what Windows describes as the "Signature Hash Algorithm".
Obviously I can construct a big switch statement in my own code, but that will break over time as new algorithms are released.
The question is, what Windows API call will return to me szOID_NIST_sha256 when given szOID_RSA_SHA256RSA?
